# Cognos 11 with ST_GEOMETRY column type

Tags: cognos

I am trying to import metadata from the schema which have tables with **ST_GEOMETRY** column type. It is throwing

> ORA-01427: Subquery returns more than one row

. 
With the tables without **ST_GEOMETRY** the improt is fine.
Please suggest if we need to do some extra setting for importing this type of data.

Regards

Panna Modi

Answer (score 0):

Do one of two things:

1. Have your data architect design and your database administrator
   implement views for these tables.  The views should omit the
   geometry columns.  Alternatively, if you need the geometry in Cognos
   for some reason, they can convert the geometry to text.
2. In the query that defines the query subject, specify the columns you
   want rather than using SELECT *.  Again, you can use the appropriate SQL functions to convert the geometry to WKT if needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I have used sde.st_astext(SHAPE) SHAPE_wkt to convert Geometry to WKT.